# PHP Parsing Error Line 19

Tags: php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in
>   /home/content/71/8956371/html/database/connect.php on line 19

The code looks fine to me: take a look at connect.php

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("timereliefusers.db.8956371.hostedresource.com", "*", "*") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("timereliefusers") or die (mysql_error());


$choice =(int) $_GET["choice"];

switch ($choice) {
    case 1:
    mysql_query("UPDATE poll1 set choice1 = choice1 + 1");
    break;
    case 2:
    mysql_query("UPDATE poll1 set choice2 = choice2 + 1");
    break;
    case 3:
    mysql_query("UPDATE poll3 set choice3 = choice3 + 1");
    break;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: remove the last `}` from the code ... the error is pretty self explanatory !

Comment: Have you even tried fixing it? Line 19 as Tom below says and most importantly as your error shows, there's an unnecessary `}` => remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not doing this:?

```
<?php

mysql_connect("timereliefusers.db.8956371.hostedresource.com", "*", "*") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("timereliefusers") or die (mysql_error());


$choice = (int) $_GET["choice"];

switch ($choice) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
      mysql_query("UPDATE poll1 set choice" . $choice . " = choice" . $choice. " + 1");
      break;
    case 3:
      mysql_query("UPDATE poll3 set choice" . $choice . " = choice" . $choice. " + 1");
      break;
}


?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, you've got an unexpected } on line 19. That means there's a } that doesn't belong there, on line 19.

Comment: Youre right, I feel stupid lol.

Answer (score 1):

```
switch ($choice) {
    case 1:
    mysql_query("UPDATE poll1 set choice1 = choice1 + 1");
    break;
    case 2:
    mysql_query("UPDATE poll1 set choice2 = choice2 + 1");
    break;
    case 3:
    mysql_query("UPDATE poll3 set choice3 = choice3 + 1");
    break;
}
}
```

should be

```
switch ($choice) {
    case 1:
    mysql_query("UPDATE poll1 set choice1 = choice1 + 1");
    break;
    case 2:
    mysql_query("UPDATE poll1 set choice2 = choice2 + 1");
    break;
    case 3:
    mysql_query("UPDATE poll3 set choice3 = choice3 + 1");
    break;
}
// removed the last "}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra "}" on line 19. There is no matching "{" earlier in the file. Line 17 contains the closing "}" for the switch statement on line 7.